# Does there exists any locally compact haussdoff space $(X, \tau) $ which is totally disconnected but not zero dimensional?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, connectedness, separation-axioms, zero-dimensionality

• $(X, \tau)$ is zero dimensional if it has a clopen basis.

• $(X, \tau)$ is totally disconnected if it all components has cardinality $1$.

•$(X, \tau)$ is locally compact haussdoff space if $\forall X$ and $\forall U_x\in \tau$ containing $x$ there exists $V_x\in \tau$ such that $x\in \overline{V_x}\subset U_x$ where
$\overline{V_x}$ is compact.

---

My question:

1. Does there exists any locally compact haussdoff space $(X, \tau) $ which is totally disconnected but not zero dimensional?
2. Does there exists any locally compact haussdoff space $(X, \tau) $ which is zero dimensional but not totally disconnected?

We know a zero dimensional haussdoff space is necessarily totally disconnected. So the answer of $2$ is "no".

If the answer of $1$ is " No" , can we replace locally compact haussdoff space by a regular space  to get the answer "Yes"?

Comment: The answer to the first question is also "no". According to *Topological Groups and Related Structures* by  Alexander Arhangelskii and Mikhail Tkachenko, Propositon 3.1.7. on page 136 we have: A totally disconnected locally compact Hausdorff space is zero-dimensional (using the small inductive dimension).

Comment: "locally compact" cannot be replaced by "regular": There exist even separable metric spaces, which are totally disconnected but not zero-dimensional, for instance the "Erdös space", see Engelking, General topology 6.2.19 or [Wikipdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space).